# Why do I have access to this file?

Tags: linux, github-enterprise

I have this file:

```
-rw-rw----+  1 git    git    16959 Jul 25 07:37 github.conf
```

I am this guy:

```
$ whoami
admin
$ id
uid=501(admin) gid=501(admin) groups=501(admin),4(adm)
```

I can also say this:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep admin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
admin:x:501:501:,,,:/home/admin:/bin/bash

$ cat /etc/group | grep -E 'admin|git'
adm:x:4:admin
git:x:500:
admin:x:501:admin
```

How is it possible I can read this file `github.conf`. I don't belong to the `git` group and I am not `git`. How is it then possible?

Comment: It looks you have extended permissions on the file (signified by the +) when listing the permissions. run "getfacl github.conf" to see the extended access control list permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have extended permissions on the file (signified by the +) when listing the permissions. run:

```
getfacl github.conf
```

to see the extended access control list permissions

Comment: In fact I get `user:admin:rw-` I didn't notice the `+` char on the permissions

Comment: You can modify the permissions with "setfacl" if you ever need to.